# Regex inside array in mongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i want to do a query inside a array in mongodb with regex, the collections have documents like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53340d07d6429d27e1284c77"),
"company" : "New Company",
"worktypes" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Pompas",
        "works" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "name 2",
                "code" : "A00011",
                "price" : "22,22"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "name 3",
                "code" : "A00011",
                "price" : "22,22"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "name 4",
                "code" : "A00011",
                "price" : "22,22"
            }, 
            {
                "code" : "asdasd",
                "name" : "asdads",
                "price" : "22"
            }, 
            {
                "code" : "yy",
                "name" : "yy",
                "price" : "11"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "name 4",
        "works" : [ 
            {
                "code" : "A112",
                "name" : "Nombre",
                "price" : "11,2"
            }
        ]
    },          
    {
        "name" : "ee",
        works":[

            {
                "code" : "aa",
                "name" : "aa",
                "price" : "11"
            }, 
            {
                "code" : "A00112",
                "name" : "Nombre",
                "price" : "12,22"
            }
              ]
    }
]
```

}

Then i need to find a document by the company name and any work inside it have match a regex in code or name work. 
I have this:

```
var companyquery = { "company": "New Company"};
var regQuery = new RegExp('^A0011.*$', 'i');

db.categories.find({$and: [companyquery,
            {$or: [
                {"worktypes.works.$.name": regQuery},
                {"worktypes.works.$.code": regQuery}
            ]}]})
```

But dont return any result..I think the error is try to search inside array with de dot and $..
Any idea?

Edit:

With this:

```
db.categories.find({$and: [{"company":"New Company"},
            {$or: [
                {"worktypes.works.name": {"$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$"}},
                {"worktypes.works.code": {"$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$"}}
            ]}]})
```

This is the result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53340d07d6429d27e1284c77"),
    "company" : "New Company",
    "worktypes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Pompas",
            "works" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "name 2",
                    "code" : "A00011",
                    "price" : "22,22"
                }, 
                {
                    "code" : "aa",
                    "name" : "aa",
                    "price" : "11"
                }, 
                {
                    "code" : "A00112",
                    "name" : "Nombre",
                    "price" : "12,22"
                }, 
                {
                    "code" : "asdasd",
                    "name" : "asdads",
                    "price" : "22"
                }, 
                {
                    "code" : "yy",
                    "name" : "yy",
                    "price" : "11"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "name 4",
            "works" : [ 
                {
                    "code" : "A112",
                    "name" : "Nombre",
                    "price" : "11,2"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Bombillos"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Pompas"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Bombillos 2"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Other type"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Other new type"
        }
    ]
}
```

The regex dont field the results ok..

Comment: What is `regexQuery `?

Comment: Its a string with value for regex, i have copy my code from nodejs client, i will edit my questio. Thanls

Comment: I think one of the problems is that the positional operator `$` is a projection/update operator, not a query operator, try something closer to: `"worktypes.works.name"` rather than `"worktypes.works.$.name"`

Comment: Same result..nothing to show :(

Comment: Wait what result do you want? That document does fill the results

Comment: I want to discad the works that not math the regex expresion, for only get works with name or code with A001.

Comment: You will need to use the aggregation framework, unwinding twice, and then regrouping

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using a JavaScript native `RegExp` object for the regular expression, however for mongo to process the regular expression it needs to be sent as part of the query document, and this is not the same thing.

Also the regex will not match the values that you want. It could actualy be `^A0111$` for the exact match, but your case insensitive match causes a problem causing a larger scan of a possible index. So there is a better way to write that. Also see the documentation link for the problems with case insensitive matches.

Use the [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator instead:

```
db.categories.find({
    "$and": [
        {"company":"New Company"},
        { "$or": [
            { "worktypes.works.name": { "$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$" }},
            { "worktypes.works.code": { "$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$" }}
        ]}
    ]
})
```

Also the positional `$` placeholders are not valid for a query, they are only used in projection or an update or the **first** matching element found by the query.

But your actual problem seems to be that you are trying to only get the elements of an array that "match" your conditions. You cannot do this with `.find()` and for that you need to use [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) instead:

```
db.categories.aggregate([

    // Always makes sense to match the actual documents
    { "$match": {
        "$and": [
            {"company":"New Company"},
            { "$or": [
                { "worktypes.works.name": { "$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$" }},
                { "worktypes.works.code": { "$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$" }}
            ]}
        ]
    }},

    // Unwind the worktypes array
    { "$unwind": "$worktypes" },

    // Unwind the works array
    { "$unwind": "$worktypes.works" },

    // Then use match to filter only the matching entries
    { "$match": {
       "$or": [
            { "worktypes.works.name": { "$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$" } },
            { "worktypes.works.code": { "$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$" } }
        ]
    }},

    /* Stop */
    // If you "really" need the arrays back then include all the following
    // Otherwise the steps up to here actually got you your results

    // First put the "works" array back together
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "company": "$company",
            "workname": "$worktypes.name"
        },
        "works": { "$push": "$worktypes.works" }
    }},

    // Then put the "worktypes" array back
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "company": { "$first": "$_id.company" },
        "worktypes": {
            "$push": {
                "name": "$_id.workname",
                "works": "$works"
            } 
        } 
    }}
])
```

So what [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) does with all of these stages is it breaks the array elements into normal document form so they can be filtered using the **`$match`** operator. In that way, only the elements that "match" are returned.

What "find" is correctly doing is matching the "document" that meets the conditions. Since documents contain the elements that match then they are returned. The two principles are very different things.

When you mean to "filter" use aggregate.

Comment: @colymore Well the document in the result does actually contain elements that match the expression. So are you actually trying to "filter" the results of the array to only return the matches? That is a different thing.

Comment: Im trying to get only the worktypes.works that his worktype.work.code or name match the regex expression, and discard the worktypes.works that not..

Comment: The RegExp object will be translated to the BSON regex object just as it shows in the documentation. The BSON regex object does not directly translate to the $regex operator.

Comment: @colymore Which is what I said in my comment. You are actually asking for something that "find" does not do. See the additional information.

Comment: @Sammaye you seem to be refering to the mongo shell usage of regular expressions. This is not the same as working with the native driver for node or most other languages. The conversion to not using the RegExp JavaScript object type actually worked from the edit posted by the OP. The only problem is the interpretation that the expected result was to only return the matching array elements.

Comment: @NeilLunn i try with your code, but dont return any result inside result array..I need to edit some ( to "compile" correct, but dont return results..

Comment: @colymore did you actually stop when the comments told you to stop. The rest of the stages should not be required for what you seem to want. I mainly want you to see the difference between matching documents and matching array elements.

Comment: @colymore So I actually have spent the time and replicated your data and ran though the final aggregate expression given. Edits are in the response, and the full chain works as expected. So there is no reason for you to not accept this. I have pointed out several problems with your original approach and given a correct solution to actually filter the array. It would be decent to actually accept the advise you are given :)

Comment: @colymore It might also help if you actually accepted the answers to the other questions you have asked. Or at least accepted the right ones :) And if you also up-voted helpful information.

Answer (score 2):

i think there is a typo :

the regex should be : `^A00011.*$`

triple 0 instead of double 0

Comment: Not, same result. I have tried with most of codes and names but any isnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try aggregate method and aggregation array operators, so this query will be supported from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$match` to match your condition
- `$addFields` to add/edit field in document
- `$map` to iterate loop of `worktypes` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `works` array and it will return the filtered result as per provided condition
- `$regexMatch` to match regex expression same as we did in `$match` stage, it will return a boolean response, so we checked `$or` condition here,
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object of `worktypes` and updated `works` array property
- second `$addFields` for remove empty result of `works` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `worktypes` array and check negative condition to remove empty `works` document

```
db.categories.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { "company": "New Company" },
        {
          $or: [
            { "worktypes.works.name": { "$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$" } },
            { "worktypes.works.code": { "$regex": "^A00011$|^a00011$" } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      worktypes: {
        $map: {
          input: "$worktypes",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                works: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$this.works",
                    cond: {
                      $or: [
                        {
                          $regexMatch: {
                            input: "$$this.name",
                            regex: "^A00011$|^a00011$"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          $regexMatch: {
                            input: "$$this.code",
                            regex: "^A00011$|^a00011$"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      worktypes: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$worktypes",
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this.works", []] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/esQ5wfFt0Ex)